# Confusing behavior of the .bat file execution from the finish page of NSIS installer

Tags: batch-file, 32bit-64bit, nsis

I'd like to let user to execute the installed application via a .bat file from the installation finish page. That's the code:

`!define INSTALL_DIR $PROGRAMFILES64\(some folder)
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "LaunchLink"
Function LaunchLink
    SetOutPath "${INSTALL_DIR}"
    ExpandEnvStrings $0 %COMSPEC%
    Exec '"$0" /C "${INSTALL_DIR}\my.bat"'
FunctionEnd`

It works as expected in most cases. But in case I have both:
**C:\Program Files\(some folder)** and
**C:\Program Files (x86)\(some folder)**
With **my.bat** file available in both of them, I get the one in the **Program Files (x86)** executed. I also tried to hardcode exact path to the .bat file  instead of using ${INSTALL_DIR} constant, but still the same issue.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you change the /C to /K you can inspect the commandline of cmd.exe in Process Explorer. Is NSIS passing the correct path to your batch file?

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the system is x32 or x64 in your bat file and if you are on a x64 system delegate a call to the x32 file to the x64 file:

```
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86
(
    START "" C:\pathto\x86version.exe
) ELSE (
    START "" C:\pathto\x64version.exe
)
```

`%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`is a system variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the goal is to prevent wrong .bat from being executed, not to add some workaround to the wrong .bat